# mongod service is not starting after making changes in mongod.conf file with root

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mongo-shell

I have created a mongoDB VM instance in GAP, and I have a php application which is deployed in google app engine, in that application I want to add mongoDB,

for which I have created a mongo VM in GAP which have an internal and external IP,
so for the mongo connectivity, I was trying to add the external IP of the mongo VM instance in the **mongod.conf** file, which is present in **etc/mongod.conf**

So, when I try to make changes in the **mongod.conf** file i.e. if I try to change the bindIP from 0.0.0.0 to the external IP of mongoDB VM instance, the changes are possible

and after that when I try to restart the mongo service and check its status it gives me the below error

which gives me the below error

```
root@mongodb-3-servers-vm-0:/# sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-02-07 05:42:47 UTC; 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 1691 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 1691 (code=exited, status=2)
```

i checked the logs in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

it says

2022-02-15T10:42:04.768+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

**below is my mongod.conf file**
(bindIP in the file is set to internal IP for now)

```
#mongod.conf

#for documentation of all options, see:

#http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

#Where and how to store data.

storage: 

dbPath: /mnt/mongodb/db

journal:

   enabled: true

#engine:

#mmapv1:

#wiredTiger:

#where to write logging data.

systemLog:

   destination: file

   logAppend: true

   path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

 #network interfaces

 #MongoDB 3.0.x *debian* packages set bind_ip to 127.0.0.1 by default
 #Compute Engine public addresses are properly firewalled by default
 #set bind_ip to 0.0.0.0 to emulate pre-2.6 behavior which eases 
 maintenance

 net:

    port: 27017

    bindIp: 10.172.0.5

#processManagement:

security:

    authorization: enabled

#keyFile: replace_me

#operationProfiling:

replication:

     replSetName: rs0

#sharding:

#Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Comment: Please show us the `/etc/mongod.conf` file, most likely a simple typo. Did you check the mongod log file (typically at `/var/log/mongod/mongod.log`)

Comment: .......
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 0.0.0.0
#processManagement:
#security:
  #authorization: enabled
  #keyFile: replace_me
.......

this is mongod.conf file, cant copy whole

Comment: Please edit your question an put additional information there instead of a comment.

Comment: Again, place provide the `/etc/mongod.conf` file and check the mongod logfile!! I am quite sure, it will show the problem instantly.

Comment: i have pasted you the mongod.conf file, into 2 parts

Comment: I give up, sorry!

Comment: Do you really expect me to read these mal-formatted comments? Read my third comment!

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, i have added the mongod.conf file in question now, 
bind ip i have set ti internal IP for now bcoz that doesn't give the error   

2022-02-15T10:42:04.768+0000 E STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Cannot assign requested address

so provide me a solution where i can do my connectivity of php application with mongodb

Comment: `bindIp: localhost,<IP's of all other replica set members>` or better `bindIpAll: true`. If you like to prevent servers connecting to the MongoDB then you should implement this by firewall rules.

Comment: lets say if i give bindIP: internal ip's of all replicate set 

or 

bindIpAll: true

then what would be the connection string i should use to connect my php with mongo

Comment: That's a different topic than "service not starting". Please create a separate question for it.

Comment: With authentication enabled, you also need to specify a keyfile.

Comment: I have added a separate question for this issue please refer this link   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71221751/no-suitable-servers-found-serverselectiontryonce-set-while-trying-to-make-co

Comment: Why are you not using `localhost` - should work better, the internal IP may change.