# No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set) while trying to make connection with mongoDB in php code

Tags: php, mongodb, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, mongo-shell

I have a php application which is deployed on google app engine , and I want to integrate my application with mongoDB database,

So for the same, I have installed a mongoDB VM in my GAP, so the instance obviously has internal and external IP,

To make a connection , in mongoDB VM I have edited the file mongod.conf file , in which I have added internal IP of my VM to bindIP part, along with security enabled also.

So when I check the connection using below connection string in my php code

mongodb://10.172.0.5:27017/?authSource=admin       (where 10.172.0.5 is the internal IP of mongoDB VM and admin is the database)

I get below error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught MongoDB\Driver\Exception\ConnectionTimeoutException: No suitable servers found (`serverSelectionTryOnce` set): [connection timeout calling hello on '10.172.0.5:27017']
```

so what should I to make a successful connection

Comment: Did you start the MongoDB? An `authSource=admin` without username/password does not make much sense.

Comment: I havent created the username yet in mongod, so was just passing the database name, also you were saying we need to specify some keyfile, could you tell me more about this

Comment: Follow this one https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/deploy-replica-set-with-keyfile-access-control/

Comment: @JanviKadu can you please let us know if the above comment solves your issue?

Comment: keyfile would come into picture if i have replicate sets, but when i had created the mongoDB instance i had specifies only 1 instance so no replica sets of the VM were created

Comment: I'm still little confused please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: Can you please provide your app.yaml file please?